# Write a program to input elements in array then print all unique elements in array. Input array elements:1 1 2 2 3,, i want to find the unrepeated num

Tags: visual-c++

i need answer in simple c++

like the code im using it prints me the repeated nums

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int arr[5], arr2[5], i = 0, j = 0;
    
    cout << "enter elements of array:\n";
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
        cin >> arr[i];  }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])break;
            
        }
    
        if (i == j) cout << arr[i];
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop your array and nest another loop into it to see whether you already found the element.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    bool found = false;
    int array[] = {1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 5, 2, 7};
    int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        found = false;
        for (int j = 0; (!found) && (j < i); j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) found = true;
        }
        if (!found) std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

You can also create an `std::set` and attempt to `insert` all array elements and print them out whenever it succeeds (which means they are encountered for the first time):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 5, 2, 7};
    int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    std::set<int> myset;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (myset.insert(array[i]).second) {
            std::cout << array[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```